# Unable to access router even though internet works

Tags: router, internet, isp

I had access to my router and my internet was also working fine, but I was trying to do a port forward of 80 to my local machine and in the process I made a mistake. I went into Remote Management and for port 80 there were a few options like `LAN`, `WAN`, `All`. I accidently clicked "`all`" and then clicked "`Disable`".

The problem is that I am no more able to access my router using 192.168.1.1, although my internet works. If I do a ping 192.168.1.1 I am able to receive the response, but I am no longer able to browse the internet. How can I fix this issue?

I am using a `zyxel p-660hn-t1a` router given by my ISP.

Comment: maybe your router has ssh or telnet, those don't depend on port 80

Comment: Also, why'd you set up port forwarding? I thought that was only when you had more than one router.

Comment: "although my internet works" (...) "but I am no longer able to browse the internet" HUH?!?!

Answer (score 5):

You probably disabled the web interface of your router (which should be, by default, on port 80). You should look in the [manual](http://www.zyxel.com/support/download_library/product/p_660hn_t1a_12.shtml) about how you to reset the router to default settings. This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

See if it will work on `https://192.198.1.1` https uses secure-sockets layer which defaults to port 443 instead of port 80. If not you may have to do a hardware-reset of the router, according to it's manual. (There is a recessed reset button on most routers that allows you to set all options to default.) You'll then have to setup the router from scratch.

Answer (score -1):

Do this instruction as it say's otherwise your modem will not reset to factory default.

If you think you made the proper reset. Open your web browser and access your modem. You should be able to see your modem/router web page configurator login page.

How to use the Reset button?

1. Turn your P-660HN-T1A on. Make sure the POWER led is on (not blinking)
2. Press the RESET button for longer than one second and shorter than five seconds and release it.
3. Press the RESET button for six seconds and then release it. If the POWER LED begins to blink, the default configuration has been restored and the P-660HN-T1A restarts.